# install Ubuntu 12.04 system requirements

Tags: 12.04, system

My computer's information:

```
  Processor Intel Pentium 4 3.00ghz (2CPU)
   2046MB RAM
```

Can I install Ubuntu 12.04? Or will it be slow ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the minimum requirements taken directly from the [ubuntu system requirements page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

**Your machine should definitely be able to run ubuntu.**

You can also always use an [ubuntu live cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) to try out ubuntu and see if it suits you. =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is adequate specs for Ubuntu to run.

[Ubuntu System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)